# Store a single value in variable with SQL Select

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have the following vba code. I am using MS Excel 2013. (I have an insert statement in this code as well, but I didn't copy this just to have a better highlight of my problem)

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim cUserEmail As String
Dim strSqlmail As String
Dim rss As Object
Dim strConnection As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\ActionList.accdb"

strSqlmail = "SELECT [Email-Adress] FROM MyTable WHERE Name='Test'"

Set rss = cn.Execute(strSqlmail)
cUserEmail = rss.Fields(0).Name
```

At this point it stores the column name (Email-Adress) in my variable. Running the query in Access returns the column with only my desired value in it.

I think I'm as good as finished, but I cannot seem to find how to get the value. When i change to rss.Field(1) it gives an error saying that the item cannot be found.

Comment: Presumably `cn` is your connection?  You need more of the code shown to give context to the question and expose your variables a little better. Either way, you are correct that `cn.Execute` isn't returning a string, if it's an `ADO` connection it will return an `ADO.Recordset`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `ADO` library then the `Execute` method returns a `RecordSet` - see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675023(v=vs.85).aspx).

So you need to:

```
Dim rsResult as Recordset
...
Set rsResult = cn.Execute(strSqlmail)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs!Email-Adress
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

So, when you add your `WHERE` clause to only return one row, then the loop should only iterate once. Whatever is output to the immediate window is what you should assign to `cUserEmail`.

Comment: I have edited my post. It shows my almost-solution so far. Do you know how to continue on my mindset? I always prefer to use code that I understand myself and would re-use if needed.

Comment: Try `rss.Fields(0).Value` instead of `rss.Fields(0).Name` in your code. If it works for you I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gave me the requested value:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim cUserEmail As String
Dim strSqlmail As String
Dim rss As Object
Dim strConnection As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\ActionList.accdb"

strSqlmail = "SELECT [Email-Adress] FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.[Name]='Test'"

Set rss = cn.Execute(strSqlmail)
cUserEmail = rss.Fields(0)
```